# SAP HANA - Monitor ressource access

Tags: monitoring, hana

I would need to monitor several key performance indicator (KPI) in SAP Hana.
For example :

- the number of times a view is executed (global)
- which users have executed a view

Is it possible with SAP Hana ? Where is this information ?
Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable auditing for the views/tables you're interested in.